# Get a node list which sub-node value is not found somewhere else in the XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to make the following for-each work.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="DATA[not(SUB1 and SUB2) 
 or ((SUB1 or SUB2) and count(//PERSON[SUB1=current()/SUB1 and SUB2=current()/SUB2] )=0)]">
```

It is grammatically correct but it does not work. I tried adding a dot after `current()`, but it does not work either.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="DATA[not(SUB1 and SUB2) 
 or ((SUB1 or SUB2) and count(//PERSON[SUB1=current()/./SUB1 and SUB2=current()/./SUB2])=0 )]">
```

I have the feeling that the problem is the `current()`. It does not work with `self::` either. I want the `current()/SUB1` refers to the sub-node of DATA.

If I remove the test from `<xsl:for-each>` and put it in an `<xsl:if>` after the for-each I can make it work fine. It does not in the for-each statement.

```
<xsl:for-each select="DATA">
    <xsl:if test="not(SUB1 and SUB2) or ((SUB1 or SUB2) and count(//PERSON[SUB1=current()/SUB1 and SUB2=current()/SUB2])=0)">
         ....
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is a test XML:

```
<ROOT>
    <PERSON>
        <SUB1>11</SUB1>
        <SUB2>AA</SUB2>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <SUB1>22</SUB1>
        <SUB2>BB</SUB2>
    </PERSON>
    <DATA>
        <SUB1>99</SUB1>
        <SUB2>ZZ</SUB2>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <SUB1>22</SUB1>
        <SUB2>BB</SUB2>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
    </DATA>
</ROOT>
```

it should select these `<DATA>` blocks since one has no SUB sub-nodes and the other has but there is no person with those SUB values:

```
    <DATA>
        <SUB1>99</SUB1>
        <SUB2>ZZ</SUB2>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
    </DATA>
```

Comment: Please add a sample XML in input, and an example of what you would like to obtain. Thanks.

Comment: `current()` refers to the current node, and in your first example that is (probably) `ROOT`. I say "probably*, since you don't show the context in which this is called. Overall, using a *key* would be a better approach to take here, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="ROOT">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="DATA" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template
    match="DATA[empty(SUB1) and empty(SUB2)] |
           DATA[SUB1 or SUB2]
               [every $data in .
                 satisfies empty(/ROOT/PERSON[SUB1=$data/SUB1 and SUB2=$data/SUB2])]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DATA" />
```

---

Using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 (and likely to be more efficient for a large number of PERSON):

```
<xsl:key name="person"
         match="PERSON"
         use="concat(SUB1, '&#xFFFC;', SUB2)" />

<xsl:template match="ROOT">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="DATA" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template
    match="DATA[not(SUB1) and not(SUB2)] |
           DATA[SUB1 or SUB2]
               [not(key('person', concat(SUB1, '&#xFFFC;', SUB2)))]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DATA" />
```

Comment: Terrific !!. I would use the second one as I am using version 1.0. I know you demonstrated it within a template and I assume it works (I'll test it) as well for a for-each. the use of keys is actually new for me.

Comment: Yes, it would work in an `xsl:for-each`.  Reasons for using templates rather than `xsl:for-each` include that it can make your stylesheet more resilient to changes in the source XML -- e.g., if you changed to have to do something with `PERSON` elements -- and that multiple shorter templates that each do a single thing can be easier to understand.  There is a counter-argument that putting it all in one `xsl:for-each` can make it easier to understand, so in the end it's a matter of preference.